# Which script is causing hang in IE9?

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

One of my WordPress pages is causing IE9 (win7 32bit) to become unresponsive and give the following dialog:

lolabeta.com is not responding due to a long-running script.  [Stop script] [x]

Here is the page URL for anyone who wants to take a look:

http://lolabeta.com/cupcakes/coconut-margarita/

This page does not hang in Chrome or Firefox, but does in IE8 and possibly other IE versions.  I don't need a diagnosis, necessarily, but wonder if there is some way to get IE to tell me *which* script is causing its problem?

Comment: I have this same issue with at least one webpage on my WordPress blog where Chrome and Firefox both do fine:
http://www.eenmanierom.nl/prezi/

I've been searching for hours now but can't find out what is causing the issue. Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 shows the visitor a pop up "is not responding due to a long-running script" and offers to stop the script. The visitor is unable to view this specific blogpost. IE's'debugger changed a so the screenshot below doesn't match up. I can't find anything in the debugger though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your page with the debugger open (press F12), click on the script tab, then click 'Start Debugging', you can see which file caused it.

[image: Screenshot]

The culprit is jquery.js, line 6047, character 5. However, it's more likely that one of your scripts is calling jquery in a tight loop. I would remove each script tag until the error stops happening.

Another debugging technique is to add a break point at the line mentioned above and check the call stack. It may be very tedious if there are other places in the code calling the same function but are not causing the problem. So, I would start by removing script tags, once you find the real culprit, remove all other script tags, and check the stack trace. Warning: This is not going to be fun

Good luck

Comment: Since you're new here, let me remind you that we vote up useful answers to build the reputation of the person that took the time to answer it.

Comment: Hi Juan -- Would love to but need more reputation to be allowed :)

Answer (score 1):

IE9 running on Vista. My Explorer suddenly became virtually unusable today, constantly displaying the long-running script error message and freezing up. Long story short, I found that an Add-on toolbar, called Linkury, had somehow got installed into my explorer program. Although I had closed the extra toolbar on the screen, it was still running in the background. In IE go to Tools, Manage Add-ons, scroll down to Linkury and disable. That may fix your problem. It fixed mine right away. I confirmed it by enabling it again and the problem came back right away. I also went into programs and uninstalled Linkury. Hope that helps. Phil